# JavaFX: Disable recycle of cells on ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a ListView with a cell factory. Each cell has a VBox, showing a various amount of ImageViews as children.

Everything works fine, but when I scroll through my list, some cells get  very big with a lot of blank space (probably due to recycling of Cells with a lot of pictures).

Is there a possibility to disable recycling of cells and always create them from ground up?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to turn that off. Your options are 1. see if you can write your cell's `updateItem(...)` method in a way that ensures this doesn't happen, or 2. Just use a `VBox` in a scroll pane, instead of the list view. The latter would lose the selection functionality, so if you are using selection you would have to implement it yourself with the second approach.

Comment: There is a way to disable this behavior: Reimplementing the skin (which would probably be a lot of work). However probably you're loading some images in the `updateItem` method, which could take some time depending on the size of the images. Comming up with a way to load the data in advance/cache the images or similar strategies could greatly improve the user experience.